# How to display all the data in the $scope without ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

New to this and been stuck for sometime. Here the `console.log` displays the correct values. I am not sure how to display all the values in the view. I tried this and it does not work.

```
function appendData(response, index)
     {
        $scope.polls[index] = response;
        // console.log($scope.polls[index]);

        var labels = [];
        var data = [];
        $scope.polls[index].data = data;

        // console.log($scope.polls[index].data);
        for (var i = 0; i < response.response.options.length; i++) {
            labels.push(response.response.options[i].options);
            data.push(response.response.options[i].votes);

        }

         // $scope.data=[data]

            // angular.forEach($scope.data,function(value,index){
            //     // alert(value.name);
            //     $scope.data =  [{data}]
            // })


        $scope.labels = labels;
        $scope.data = [data];

        // console.log(data);
        console.log($scope.data);


    }
```

My View

```
<div>
<canvas id="base" class="chart chart-bar"  chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" ></canvas>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of the Bars repeating]

Comment: what is the chart library you are using?

Comment: It seems like your $scope.data is an array within an array. Is that what you really need? Doesn't `$scope.data = data` work better? Also, series (which you use in your html) seem to be undefined

Comment: I am using the http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/ Chart Library. @AlbertoRivera That is fine. I do get the Chart shown using that but the same chart is displayed everywhere.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your chart? I am unsure if you are talking about multiple charts or bars within your chart.

Comment: I have updated. Do help, this thing is strangling me.